# Restricted capabilities on UWP apps

Tags: windows-phone, uwp, appx, appxmanifest

I want to make screen projection application. And according to MSDN I need a rescap namespace in Package.appxmanifest.
I Wrote this`xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"`, but namespace does not appears.
Do I need something more?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "namespace does not appears"? If you want to add Screen Projection Capability, you can add `<rescap:Capability Name="screenDuplication"/>` in `<Capabilities>`.

Answer (score 1):

In the Package.appxmanifest when you add the rescap namespace, add 'rescap' to the IgnorableNamespaces property.

```
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" 
     xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" 
     xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" 
     xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
     IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
```

Edited: VS tells you "Capability" aren't into "rescap" namespace and doesn't let you build the application. Adding the name to the IgnorableNamespaces let you use the "rescap" namespace without breaking the application and letting you use the restricted capability.

Answer (score 0):

To Add "Screen Projection Capability", you can include following two lines in "package.manifest":

```
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"

<Capabilities>
<rescap:Capability Name="screenDuplication "/>
</Capabilities>
```

Besides, you can find a [projection sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Projection-sample-526b3c1d#content), which use ProjectionManager and ApplicationViewSwitcher APIs.

To Cristian: I don't think his problem is related with "IgnorableNamespaces", which is more about backward capability.

Answer (score 0):

Developer account can't use the Special and restricted capabilities,for that company account has need.

Comment: how do I get a company account? Once I've got one, how does my app know I've got one?